# Search for users by timezone or country on Slack?

Tags: search, slack, user-accounts, time-zone

For example if I wanted to see all users who were in Australia, could I search for them by either a timezone or country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slack does not store the country of a user, but it stores the timezone.

It's not a standard feature to list users by timezone, but there are a couple Slack Apps that do that nicely. Check out [Team Time Zone](http://www.teamtimezone.com/) or search for similar apps in the App Directory.